# Custom culture resource files

Tags: asp.net, resources

I've created a custom culture, `Custom-en-GB`, based on `en-GB` and registered it using the `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder`.  This works fine.

In my ASP.NET application, I'm trying to create a resource file for this culture, namely `FooBar.Custom-en-GB.resx`, to supplement the `FooBar.resx` and `FooBar.en-gb.resx` I already have.

I notice that an underlying class gets created for `FooBar.Custom-en-GB.resx`, which effectively prevents it from residing in the `FooBar` resource hiearchy.

`FooBar-en-GB.resx` has no underlying class and when I access the resource with a culture of `en-GB`, then all is fine.

I'm not sure if I've explained that very well but, essentially, I think that Visual Studio isn't aware of the culture, as it's registered at runtime, and creates the underlying class.

I'd like to avoid a "hard" register of the culture if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so why didn't I think to re-start Visual Studio after the first time I registered the custom culture?  Doh!